# skaffold dev: no output to terminal (or delayed output)

Tags: python, stdout, kubectl, minikube, skaffold

### Context

I'm trying to learn skaffold. I've installed skaffold, kubectl, and minikube. I've created a Python script that prints "Hello, World!" in a loop. I've created a simple Dockerfile and Kubernetes manifest. I've generated a skaffold.yaml using `skaffold init`.

### Problem

After starting minikube with `minikube start` and running `skaffold dev`, my app was built and deployed to minikube, as expected. However, there was no further output: "Hello, World!" wasn't printed every second in the terminal, as it should have.

That said, I noticed that if I waited 5 minutes, a bunch of "Hello, World!" would appear all at once. Then nothing again for 5 minutes. Then more "Hello, Worlds!", all at once. In short, it seems to tail the logs every 5 minutes or so, instead of doing it in real time.

I thought the problem was related to my Linux computer, but I then followed the exact same steps on my Mac, and almost the same thing happened: the only difference is that it outputs every 4 minutes or so, instead of every 5.

### Question

Can you help me figure out what's happening here? I've looked at the documentation, and as far as I can tell, the expected default behavior should be real-time output to the terminal.

For what it's worth, doubling minikube's CPU and RAM changed nothing. But trying the [skaffold quickstart](https://skaffold.dev/docs/quickstart/) (which involves a similar app but written in Go) worked perfectly: the output wasn't delayed.

### Files

Here are all the app and config files to reproduce the steps above.

**app.py**

```
import time

start = time.time()

while True:
    print("Hello, World!")
    now = time.time()
    print(f"Time elapsed: {round(now - start)}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**k8s.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hello
      image: hello
```

**skaffold.yaml**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta26
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: hello-app
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: hello
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s.yaml
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `--tail`?. [Log tailing](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/log-tailing/)

Comment: `skaffold dev` should tail by default. But I did try adding the flag regardless, and I also tried `skaffold run --tail`. The problem remained: it only tailed once every 4/5 minutes instead of doing it in real time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem wasn't with Skaffold nor Minikube. Python was buffering the output, and only writing it to stdout once the buffer was full.

There are a number of [ways to avoid this](https://blog.finxter.com/what-is-python-output-buffering-and-how-to-disable-it/), including using the `-u` flag or `flush` parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Change your app.py:

```
import time

start = time.time()

while True:
    print("Hello, World!\n")
    now = time.time()
    print(f"Time elapsed: {round(now - start)}\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Adding \n when printing data should help. Though I'm not sure what's the rational behind the hood, probably some buffering (?).